# Is there a way to increase i2c read in linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c

I have an LSM6DS3 motion sensor connected to the i2c bus of a Qualcomm processor running Linux OS. I have been trying to read the FIFO buffer of the sensor every 20s. 
It takes around 2 to 3 seconds to read all the data from the sensor FIFO buffer(*The FIFO buffer of the sensor is exposed through LSM6DS3_FIFO_DATA_OUT_L and LSM6DS3_FIFO_DATA_OUT_H registers in the sensor*).
Im using `i2c_smbus_read_word_data(int file, __u8 command)` APIs to read.
In order to reduce this time delay I have set my i2c master clock to 400KHz and tried IOCTLs instead of above APIs but none of the workaround worked.
The same sensor I connected to Arduino and tried the same read operation. It took only 1.4s to read the data.
Is there any way to increase the i2c read speed in Linux?.

Comment: Does the LSM6DS3 really transmit a word (2 bytes) because you use `__s32 i2c_smbus_read_word_data(int file, __u8 command)`,if not this could be a performance issue, this is also discussed in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/479602/slow-fifo-read-from-lsm6ds3. They plan to implement a custom kernel module for this chip ...

Comment: yeah `LSM6DS3_FIFO_DATA_OUT_L` and ```LSM6DS3_FIFO_DATA_OUT_H``` are nearby addresses, the `i2c_smbus_read_word_data` does work fine and I have also tried `read()` system call on i2c node

Comment: Can you use the existing Linux driver for this chip? `CONFIG_IIO_ST_LSM6DSX` and `CONFIG_IIO_ST_LSM6DSX_I2C`. It's been in there since kernel v4.11.

Comment: And why you are not using correct way to access hardware, i.e. via in-kernel driver?

Comment: @0andriy I want to configure many registers in the sensor so I used i2c-dev driver directly.

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm not familiar with the IIO subsystem, I'm looking into that.

Comment: Are you using it in non-standard mode?

Comment: @0andriy I'm not familiar with the IIO class. so I've been using direct register read-write methods to configure the sensor sensitivity, sampling rate, interrupts, etc. Is that what you referring as standard mode?

Comment: I guess so. I believe IIO will do it for you very nicely. There is a user space library `libiio` to help with integration all this together.

Comment: @0andriy. I'm looking into direct register access via IIO. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: But why? Do you use your sensor in non-standard mode?

Comment: @0andriy what you mean by standard mode?